# Memory leak of doubly linked struct list

Tags: c++, linux, struct, memory-leaks, doubly-linked-list

I am working on a file crawler in ubuntu 16.04 linux with C++. 
The file crawler is my solution to a question from the book `Modern Operating Systems by Andrew Tanenbaum 4th edition` it reads as follows:

> Write a program that starts at a given directory and descends the file tree from that
>   point recording the sizes of all the files it finds. When it is all done, it should print a
>   histogram of the file sizes using a bin width specified as a parameter (e.g., with 1024,
>   file sizes of 0 to 1023 go in one bin, 1024 to 2047 go in the next bin, etc.).

It takes the exename, directory, and bin size as parameters and crawls through a directory adding files to bins that are stored as a doubly linkedlist. 
 
For example if `binWidth or (argv[2])` is 10 it stores files of byte size 0-9 in Bin 0 if you find a file of size 10 or greater it makes a new node with size 10-18 and stores it there and labels it Bin 1. 
 My problem occurs if I have a directory nested inside of another directory I need to open it to traverse the files recursively. I have a function `traverseNewDirectory` that is intended to go through and find them recursively.
I believe that the bug is in my copy constructor. 
 My code is below:

```
 // Directory crawler
// Written by Kaz

#include<iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int binCount = 0; // count of total bins which are nodes in the linked-list

struct node{
    int count, name, min, max;
    node* next, *prev;
    node(){
        name = binCount;
      count = 0;
        min = 0;
        max = 0;
        prev = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
    node(node *other){
        if(other == NULL){

        }
        else{
            node* objCopy = other;
            node* temp = this;
            while(objCopy != NULL){
                temp->next = new node;
                temp->next->name = objCopy->name;
                temp->next->count = objCopy->count;
                temp->next->min = objCopy->min;
                temp->next->max = objCopy->max;
                temp->next->prev = objCopy->prev;
                temp = temp->next;
                objCopy = objCopy->next;
            }
        }
    }
};
/*
void nextNode(node* previousNode, int binWidth){

        node *nextLink = new node;

        nextLink->count = 1;
        nextLink->min = previousNode->max + 1;
        nextLink->max = previousNode->max + binWidth;
        nextLink->prev = previousNode;

        previousNode ->next = nextLink;
}
*/
node* traverseNewDirectory(node *here, const char *dirName, int binWidth){
    DIR * nwd;
    struct dirent *dip;
    node * current = new node(here);
    // Deep copy?
    //current = here;
    bool isadirectory,isHidden;
    if((nwd = opendir(dirName))== NULL){
        perror("Can't open derived directory");
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((dip = readdir(nwd)) != NULL){
        isadirectory = false;
        isHidden = false;
        if((dip -> d_type) == DT_UNKNOWN ){
            struct stat stbuf;
      stat(dip->d_name, &stbuf);
      isadirectory = S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode);
        }
        else if((dip -> d_type) == DT_DIR ){
            if((strcmp(dip->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(dip->d_name, "..")) == 0){
                isHidden = true;
                isadirectory = true;

            }
            else{
                isadirectory = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            if((dip-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(dip->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                    current->count = current->count+1;
            }
            else if(dip->d_reclen < current->min){
                node*temp = current->prev;
                while(temp != NULL){
                    if((dip-> d_reclen <= temp->max)&&(dip->d_reclen >=temp->min)){
                            temp->count = temp->count+1;
                            break;
                    }
                    else if(dip->d_reclen < temp->min){
                        temp = temp->prev;
                }
            }
        }
            else{
                current->next = new node;

                current->next->count = 1;
                current->next->min = current->max + 1;
                current->next->max = current->max + binWidth;
                current->next->prev = current;

                current = current->next;
                binCount++;
            }
        }
        if(isadirectory){
            string path = string(dirName) + "/"+dip->d_name;
            /*
            strcpy(path,dirName);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path,dip->d_name);
            strcat(path, "\0");
            */
            if(isHidden == true){}
            else{
            current->next = new node(traverseNewDirectory(current, path.c_str(), binWidth));
            if(current->next != NULL){
                current = current->next;
                binCount++;
            }
            }
        }
    }
    while ( ( closedir (nwd) == -1) && ( errno == EINTR) );
    if(current == here){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        return current;
    }
}
void printHistogram(node *head){
    node*temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout << "[B " << temp->name << "] from  " << temp->min << " to " << temp->max << " : ";
        for(int i = 0; i < temp->count; i++){
            cout << "x";
        }
        cout << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    // Ensures that a valid directory is provided by the cmd line argument
    if (argc != 3){
        if(argc == 1){
            fprintf (stderr, " argc = %d no directory given  \n", argc);
            return 1;
        }
        else if(argc == 2){
        fprintf (stderr, " argc = %d no size given \n", argc);
        return 2;
        }
        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "argc = %d invalid parameters \n", argc);
            return 3;
        }
    }
    DIR * cwd; // current working directory pointer
    struct dirent *cwdP; // pointer to dirent struct
    int binWidth; // variable for the width of the grouping in the histogram
    binWidth = atoi(argv[2]);
    binWidth = binWidth - 1;
    node *first = new node;
    first->max = binWidth;
    binCount++;
    node * current;
    current = first;
    bool isadirectory,isHidden;
    if((cwd = opendir(argv[1]))== NULL){
        perror("Can't open  main directory");
        return 2;
    }

    while ((cwdP = readdir(cwd)) != NULL){
        isadirectory = false;
        isHidden  = false;
        if((cwdP -> d_type) == DT_UNKNOWN ){
            struct stat stbuf;
            stat(cwdP->d_name, &stbuf);
            isadirectory = S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode);
        }
        else if((cwdP -> d_type) == DT_DIR ){
            if((strcmp(cwdP->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(cwdP->d_name, "..")) == 0){
                isHidden = true;
                isadirectory = true;

            }
            else{
                isadirectory = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            if((cwdP-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(cwdP->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                    current->count = current->count+1;
            }
            else if(cwdP->d_reclen < current->min){
                node*temp = current->prev;
                while(temp != NULL){
                    if((cwdP-> d_reclen <= temp->max)&&(cwdP->d_reclen >=temp->min)){
                            temp->count = temp->count+1;
                            break;
                    }
                    else if(cwdP->d_reclen < temp->min){
                        temp = temp->prev;
                }
            }
        }
            else{
                /*
                nextNode(current,binWidth);
                current = current ->next;
                //binCount++;
                */
                current->next = new node;

                current->next->count = 1;
                current->next->min = current->max + 1;
                current->next->max = current->max + binWidth;
                current->next->prev = current;

                current = current->next;
                binCount++;
            }
        }
        if(isadirectory){
            string fullPath = string(argv[1]) + "/" + cwdP ->d_name;
            /*
            strcpy(path,dirName);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path,dip->d_name);
            strcat(path, "\0");
            */
            if(isHidden == true){}
            else{
            current->next = new node(traverseNewDirectory(current, fullPath.c_str(), binWidth));
            if(current->next != NULL){
                current = current->next;
                binCount++;
            }
            }
        }
    }
    while ( ( closedir (cwd) == -1) && ( errno == EINTR) );
    printHistogram(first);
    return 0;
}
```

**LAST EDIT**

I'd like to give a huge thank you to Igor, J.H ,Toby and everyone else who commented for giving me some advice on how to handle the linked list. My code now fully solves the problem. I was able to implement it by simplifying my approach from a doubly linked struct list to a singly linked struct list with only a few pointers and no copy constructor. Even though all of the answers, advice, and tips didn't give me a direct answer it sparked my creativity in such a way that through perseverance, and research I was able to solve it. And for that I want to thank everyone who took the time to view my post.

Comment: And you've exercised your copy constructor in Valgrind or some other tool, before asking the world, I presume.  What did it tell you, and what more do you need to know?

Comment: You need to check if temp->next is null

Comment: @NeilButterworth shouldn't `temp->next` be NULL if it hasn't been initialized? Since `this` is the new start of a list?

Comment: @TobySpeight no idea that even existed, it seems pretty complex. I will try to apply it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth so basically `if(temp->next == NULL) && (objCopy!=NULL)`?

Comment: You may wish to consider how to make your functions smaller - it'll lead to less mistakes as things become easier to read and you don't need to scroll to see the whole loop

Comment: @UKMonkey I considered that, I originally had smaller functions but couldn't figure out where my mem-leak was occuring so I expanded them into what they are now. So I can see it's because of the `traverseNewDirectory()` because whenever I use nested directories it yields this problem. And the copy constructor I tried to use threw things way out of whack. So I'm trying to weed it out at the source before breaking it up into smaller functions.

Comment: `node(node *other)` constructor leaves all members of `node` uninitialized when `other == NULL`, and leaves all members but `next` uninitialized otherwise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `node(node *other)` is ... well... You might laugh at me for this but it's suppposed to be a copy constructor. I had a hard time getting it to even compile trying to use it with struct and when I tried to use `node(node &other)` the compiler wouldn't let me. And I couldn't figure out a workaround

Comment: `temp->next->prev = objCopy->prev;` Nodes in the new list have their `next` pointer point to other nodes in the new list (good) - but their `prev` pointers point to old nodes in the original list. You probably meant `temp->next->prev = temp;`

Comment: You are busy allocating all these nodes, but I don't see you deleting a single one. I'm not sure why you are surprised about memory leaks - you don't appear to ever free any memory.

Comment: I think you got so many down votes because your not providing a minimal complete and verifiable example. And your question is quite weird "It takes[...]" what is 'it'?? What do you want to do. What goes wrong?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't delete nodes because I'm not quite sure how to account for it when I go inside of traverseNewDirectory with current. Inside of that function I have current and everything it's attached to previously due to the prev pointer. But when I come back I lose everything that function generates so I probably overcompensated.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius it takes 3 arguments from the command line via `argv[]`. exename(the name of the executable`argv[0]`). A directory(name of a folder `argv[1]`) and bin width (groupthe files by bytes`argv[2]`). if `binWidth` = 1024. the first bin contains files that have `0-1023` bytes. The second bin `1024- 2047` bytes etc. For argv[1] it needs a path name. So if I have a folder `demo`, in it there is `crawler.cpp`, `crawler.exe` and `repo` with repo being a directory that has files or directories. I could call the program in bash by `./crawler.exe repo 105` and the first bin would go `0-104`.

Comment: There's no decent justification for this. Just use ` std::string`  and ` std::list`. If those are banned for some insane reason (happens in bad schools), write your own generic string and list classes. Do **not** mix application logic and data structures, e.g. as happens here with a `struct node` that is both data structure (prev/next) and application-specific (count/name/min/max)

Comment: @MSalters thanks, I didn't consider using `std::list` if I can't get this implementation to work in a few more hours then I will refactor that structure into my program instead

Comment: @KazRodgers Why are you explaining it to me in the comments? Put this in your question, to make it a good question!

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Ok I am editting it in now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a copy constructor, you probably want something like this:

```
node(const node& other) {
  node* prev = nullptr;
  node* cur = this;
  const node* old_cur = &other;
  for (;;) {
    cur->count = old_cur->count;
    cur->min = old_cur->min;
    cur->max = old_cur->max;
    cur->prev = prev;
    if (old_cur->next) {
      old_cur = old_cur->next;
      cur->next = new node();
      prev = cur;
      cur = cur->next;
    } else {
      cur->next = nullptr;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Though it's not clear you even want any form of a copy or a pseudo-copy constructor. The `traverseNewDirectory` call should probably look like this:

```
current->next = traverseNewDirectory(...);
```

(drop the `new node` part).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I receive the following error:          `prog2.cpp: In function ‘node* traverseNewDirectory(node*, const char*, int)’:
prog2.cpp:67:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘node::node(node*&)’
  node * current = new node(here);`

Comment: I figured it out `node * current = new node(*here);` on line 67. But I still have the issue of the memory leak where I am either duplicating or copying nodes. I will keep working on it. But I am sure now that my bug is in the recursion and not the copy constructor.

Comment: Well, you probably don't want `new node(here)` either. I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but making a deep copy of the list makes no sense, as soon afterwards you do `current->next = new node`, thus cutting off and leaking all but the first node of that cloned list.

Comment: Say I have 1 bin `bin 0`. I enter `traverseNewDirectory()`. This generates `bin2,bin3 and bin4`. I return to `main` it generates 2 more bins 5 and 6. But when I print I get bin0, 3, 5 and 6. But 3 has the values of 1 and 2 has the values of 5. So I lose nodes right? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I see. `traverseNewDirectory` builds the whole new list, and returns a pointer to its head. You attach it to the end of the existing list (except that you never set `prev` to link back to that existing list), then advance `current` by just one node, instead of skipping all the way to the end of the new list. Once again, you effectively cut off all but the head of the list built by `traverseNewDirectory`

Comment: I was able to account for all of that by changing my approach drastically. In short I overthought the problem and ended up in pointer hell.You have been my guiding light through this tortuous journey.